# how to check microcode is enabled on my system and how to fix intel cpu firmware package which is causing reboot issues

Tags: linux, centos, cpu, intel, vulnerability

[Fixes](https://newsroom.intel.com/news/root-cause-of-reboot-issue-identified-updated-guidance-for-customers-and-partners/) from intel in there cpu firmware package seems to be causing reboot issues

I'm using `centos 7.3` distribution with `1.14.14 kernel` and want to know which package is intel's cpu firmware and which version is faulty an how to fix it.

Though I think this [microcode](https://linux.die.net/man/8/microcode_ctl) package is the correct one.

I also referred to this [doc](https://newsroom.intel.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/11/2018/01/microcode-update-guidance.pdf) but it didn't mentioned about the exact package name and version.

**System info:**

```
sh-4.2# cat /proc/cpuinfo 
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 62
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2670 v2 @ 2.50GHz
stepping    : 4
microcode   : 0x42a
cpu MHz     : 2499.980
cache size  : 25600 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 2
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 1
apicid      : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc rep_good nopl xtopology cpuid pni pclmulqdq ssse3 cx16 pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand hypervisor lahf_lm cpuid_fault pti retpoline fsgsbase smep erms xsaveopt
bugs        : cpu_meltdown spectre_v1 spectre_v2
bogomips    : 5000.16
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 1
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 62
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2670 v2 @ 2.50GHz
stepping    : 4
microcode   : 0x42a
cpu MHz     : 2499.980
cache size  : 25600 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 2
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 1
apicid      : 1
initial apicid  : 1
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc rep_good nopl xtopology cpuid pni pclmulqdq ssse3 cx16 pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand hypervisor lahf_lm cpuid_fault pti retpoline fsgsbase smep erms xsaveopt
bugs        : cpu_meltdown spectre_v1 spectre_v2
bogomips    : 5000.16
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

sh-4.2#
```

**microcode package**

```
sh-4.2# yum list installed | grep microcode
microcode_ctl.x86_64             2:2.1-22.5.el7_4                   @updates    
sh-4.2#
```

Also want to know:

1. Is microcode the correct intel cpu firmware package?
2. What microcode_ctl actually does?
3. How to map the microcode value in `/proc/cpuinfo` with `microcode_ctl` package version, in order to identify faulty package?

**Update:**

I was able to compare the package version listed by intel [here](https://newsroom.intel.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/11/2018/01/microcode-update-guidance.pdf) with my systems package. First I figured out my system `CPUID` by running these commands `yum install cpuid && cpuid | grep serial` and checked the affect version for this corresponding `CPUID` [here](https://newsroom.intel.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/11/2018/01/microcode-update-guidance.pdf). It seems I'm using the affected package `0x42a` I compared this version with the output of `cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep microcode`. The unaffected one `0x428` is this package `microcode_ctl-2.1-16.3.el7_3.x86_64`. I installed this package but but was not able to figure out whether my system have microcode enabled.

I have few more question -

1. Not sure whether my machine have `microcode` enabled at boot time. I tired these commands and it didn't output anything `dmesg | grep microcode`. I also checked this `grep -i 'microcode' /boot/config-$(uname -r)` it shows microcode config set to yes but still in boot time logs `dmesg | grep microcode` it showing nothing. Is microcode really enabled here and if not how to enable it.
2. I also referred this [blog](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/install-update-intel-microcode-firmware-linux/) to enable microcode but was stucked at this step `echo 1 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/microcode/reload` the system is not allowing to create this file even with root user.

Comment: What are the issues?

Comment: @mdpc I have updated my question and added more details. Also have modified the title.

Comment: There still are no information about the "reboot issues". What are these issues? Random reboots? Unable to reboot? Unusual reboots in some other way?

Comment: The reboot issues details are provided by intel on there official blog. You can check there. https://security-center.intel.com/advisory.aspx?intelid=INTEL-SA-00088&languageid=en-fr https://newsroom.intel.com/news/root-cause-of-reboot-issue-identified-updated-guidance-for-customers-and-partners/

Answer (score 3):

The problematic microcode with the hastily-developed mitigation for the Spectre Variant 2 vulnerability was released in January 3 for RHEL and January 4 for CentOS: https://lists.centos.org/pipermail/centos-announce/2018-January/022697.html

Later, the microcode included in that package for Broadwell and Haswell processors turned out to have problems and was rolled back:
https://access.redhat.com/errata/RHSA-2018:0093

According to the latter RedHat security advisory, your `microcode_ctl` package version 2:2.1-22.5.el7_4 is the version that already has the problem microcode rolled back. But the microcode update gets built into your `initramfs` file, so if you suspect you're still having microcode-related problems, just recreate your `initramfs` file (classically the `mkinitrd` command, or `dracut` for RHEL/Centos 7 and newer).

The `microcode_ctl` package contains both the actual microcode files and some tools to build the correct microcode update into your `initramfs` file. The actual microcode files are installed at `/lib/firmware/intel-ucode`: there are quite a few small files, one for each Intel processor model that has ever needed a microcode update.

For some Intel CPUs, it turned out that it was in some cases necessary to apply a microcode update in as early in the boot process as possible, to avoid certain hardware bugs.

(More specifically, Intel processors with /proc/cpuinfo model code 79 and original microcode the update process was unreliable if `/sys/devices/system/cpu/microcode/reload` was used while the system was running in normal SMP mode. This bug could be avoided by either having the BIOS install the microcode update or installing the update at early boot while the boot process has not yet started all the cores and was still running on just one core.)

For this purpose, an "early microcode load" facility was developed in Linux. If the initrd/initramfs file contains a file named `kernel/x86/microcode/GenuineIntel.bin` (for Intel) or `kernel/x86/microcode/AuthenticAMD.bin` (for AMD), the kernel attempts to load it as a microcode update very early in the boot process. *No user-space tools are required for this functionality*.

On RHEL/Centos 7, to see if your initramfs file contains an early microcode update file, run this command:

```
lsinitrd /boot/initramfs-$(uname -r).img | less
```

If the beginning of the output looks like this, a microcode update is included:

```
Image: /boot/initramfs-3.10.0-693.el7.x86_64.img: 20M
========================================================================
Early CPIO image
========================================================================
drwxr-xr-x   3 root     root            0 Oct 11 05:11 .
-rw-r--r--   1 root     root            2 Oct 11 05:11 early_cpio
drwxr-xr-x   3 root     root            0 Oct 11 05:11 kernel
drwxr-xr-x   3 root     root            0 Oct 11 05:11 kernel/x86
drwxr-xr-x   2 root     root            0 Oct 11 05:11 kernel/x86/microcode
-rw-r--r--   1 root     root        12288 Oct 11 05:11 kernel/x86/microcode/GenuineIntel.bin
========================================================================
Version: dracut-033-502.el7

Arguments: -f -v

[... main initrd contents skipped ...]
```

Besides the actual microcode files, the `microcode_ctl` RPM package contains the following things:

- `/usr/lib/dracut/dracut.conf.d/01-microcode.conf`, the file that tells the `dracut` (the initramfs creator) to add the early microcode update to the initramfs file.
- `/usr/lib/systemd/system/microcode.service` which uses `/sys/devices/system/cpu/microcode/reload` to load the microcode update in case the early microcode update was disabled or failed to run. It has a special exception for Intel CPUs with model code 79: on these CPUs it does nothing at all.
- `/usr/sbin/intel-microcode2ucode`, a tool for converting the Intel microcode file to a format that is usable by the Linux microcode update mechanism.
- a README file in `/usr/share/doc/microcode_ctl/README`.

If you are running on a virtual machine, then you don't have to care about microcode updates - that's a job for the administrator of the virtualization host, a VM *can not* do it. Even if you have `microcode_ctl` package installed, it will do nothing at all if you're running on a VM.

To roll back the problematic microcode, you need to eliminate all the sources of the problematic microcode from your system:

- roll back any firmware upgrades that include the problem firmware
- make sure the `microcode_ctl` package is a version that has the problem microcode rolled back (you've done this)
- make sure the initramfs file has been updated to match the installation time of the currently-installed `microcode_ctl` package

Then *power down* and reboot. A microcode is non-persistent over power cycles, but if a CPU already has a newer microcode version loaded, it won't accept a microcode update with a lower version number.

Comment: I have updated my question. Can you check and answer if possible.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: So you mean I don't need to care about microcode package in case of VM. I do see this in microcode.service status 
`● microcode.service - Load CPU microcode update
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/microcode.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
Condition: start condition failed at Thu 2018-02-01 16:33:22 UTC; 4s ago
           ConditionVirtualization=false was not met
`
So even if my system (VM) has problematic microcode it will never get enabled at boot time and I don't need to worry about it.

Comment: Yes... but if `/proc/cpuinfo` indicates your host CPU has the affected microcode, then the only way to get rid of it is to have the administrators of the physical host take care of it.

Comment: ok but we bake our own AMI's so it's our job to roll back to proper microcode version.

Comment: My point was: if you are only the administrator of the VM, you cannot do it. You need (someone else with?) physical host admin access to really manage the CPU microcode, because a VM cannot send microcode updates to the CPU: the hypervisor/host OS is the only one that can do it.

Comment: Oh then it seems the AWS job to manage it, will check with them. Thanks!